# Is setting a custom bluetooth pin secure enough?

Tags: bluetooth, arduino

I am working on a project that might be using bluetooth. It is a display board for a school near me, and it will be controlled via a smartphone.

Would setting a custom pin/passkey for the bluetooth chip be enough security to keep away people looking to mess with the display (as that is all the BT module is connected to)? Should I have another layer of security and if so, what?

Comment: Layered defense is always a good idea. user/pass might be classic, but there are also many alternatives. No sense in guessing for those without knowing a tad more information about what it is you can connect to though. Custom board with its own firmware? A fancy modern rPi with a SSHD (and hopefully kept up to date), .... something else... ?

Comment: @Hennes All I need is to keep people who do not know the pin from getting into the board and changing what is on the display.

Comment: In that case then normal BT security seems good enough. One device generates a random number. You type that number into the other device. Done.